# How to add 5 week shift schedule to calendar?

Tags: calendar, automation

I need a way to set in my work schedule which repeats over 5 weeks in the calendar, It looks like this:

```
NNNN FFF
LLL FF MM
MM FF NNN
FFF LLLL
FF MMM FF
```

(Night, Free, Late, Morning)

Is there any way to do this? I really want it in my calendar and not as a separate app, I've seen "My Work Schedule" and "Work Calendar Lite" but they're not at all what I need.

Using a Samsung Galaxy S3, hope somebody's able to help me out, this really sucks, especially since my colleagues can easily do it on their Iphone ...

Comment: I think the best way to accomplish this is to find a service which allows you to sync a suitable calendar over webcal to your Google account. I know of one such service ([WebCal.fi](http://www.webcal.fi/fi-FI/kalenterit.php)) but unfortunately it only supports Finnish shift rotations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, thinking of just using the google calendar API to solve this problem, have some experience as a webdeveloper so it shouldn't be too hard

Comment: I'm the author of WebCal.fi. Currently it only supports Finnish workshifts, but I can add this calendar in other languages as well. Please contact me (you'll find my e-mail at webcal.fi) as I need to ask a few specific questions on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is not possible within Android's calendar apps. It is possible, however, in Google Calendar's web app. If you are syncing with a Google account, you can go to [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar) and set up events to repeat every 5 weeks. You would have to set up each segment separately, but you could then set that segment to repeat every five weeks.

For example:

1. Go to Google Calendar
2. Add an event for one day of work (say, a single night shift)
3. Edit event...
4. Check box for "Repeat..."
5. In the popup that appears, set to repeat every 5 weeks, and select the days that week that have the same schedule (e.g., Mon, Tues, Wed).
6. Repeat for each segment in your schedule.

If you use the same Google account to sync your calendar to your phone, the schedule should appear shortly.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, had been meaning to post it here but completely forgot. This works great if anybody is still interested. The only problem is that it shows up all screwed up in my gf's agenda-app on her phone, though it displays fine on her google calendar a normal browser ... I'm gonna try and upgrade her phone to the latest android, hopefully that solves it ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a mobile app called [Six In A Row](http://sixinarow.io) to be released in 2019 that should be able to do this when it's ready!

UPDATE: I decided to push the rotation extension feature to the next version. v1.0 might still be helpful though; my wife put a whole year of shifts in by tapping each shift/date that she is scheduled to work and it didn't take long at all. It's in beta now (you can get the free beta version by signing up on the website).

Otherwise in Google calendar you could create individual events for each shift in one rotation, and then set them all to be repeating every x weeks or whatever. I think this is a time intensive solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

if you want just to enter your shifts and make them repeat, so you can see when you working or not, there are plenty of such apps on the android market, for example - Shift Work Schedule ( this one is free).